# Acer V3-771 Touchpad detected as ps/2 generic mouse

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, acer

I have a brand new Acer V3-771G. I can use my Touchpad fine but I can't scroll with it, because its detected as a PS/2 generic mouse:

```
    xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD Webcam                                 id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Apparently my Touchpad is detected as a PS/2 Generic Mouse. Is there a way to fix this?

I tested this with 12.04, 12.10 Alpha, and with several daily mainline kernels but still it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

A new maintainer has agreed to take over the Synaptiks project (just 20 days  ago) and I  imagine it will  take him a couple months to come up to speed.
https://github.com/lunaryorn/synaptiks/issues/55

Answer (score 0):

For all those still looking, I have an Acer Aspire v3 771g and this package: psmouse-alps-dst-0.4.tbz , works perfectly, here are installation instructions:

Extract psmouse-alps-dst-0.4 in /usr/src/ with sudo rights.
If you have installed the module before, I suggest you to completely remove it before reinstalling with:

```
sudo dkms remove psmouse/alps-dst-0.4 --all
```

(of course, if you have installed another version of the module, change version number accordingly)

Then just type these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo dkms build psmouse/alps-dst-0.4
sudo dkms install psmouse/alps-dst-0.4
sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe -v psmouse
```

After that your touchpad will be hopefully recognized by your machine.

Courtesy of [Launchpad bug 606238](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238), [comment 212](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238/comments/212) (by [quarara](https://launchpad.net/~classic-art-showcase)).